# Trying to correct Layout problems for IE7

Tags: css, layout, internet-explorer-7

Im currently working on a website for work experience and ran into a problem with the layout. The website has a navigation menu at the top with a drop down menu. The layout is fine in all browsers besides IE7. Instead of running horizontally it runs vertically. The link is below.
Please note that I have not been able to get on to the server and upload the full site so everything is wonky on it but my problem is still there to see.

http://www.cudedesign.co.uk/tester/header.php

I would be grateful for your suggestions so I can solve this before I have to go back on monday. Thank You in advance.

Comment: "so I can solve this" ... yet you want us to navigate to your site, view the code, find the issue and provide an answer?

Comment: Well what would have been better? I would like advice on a problem I have been unable to solve.

Comment: Can you please add the original pertinent code into this question so that it will be useful to folks in the future who may have the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE 7 does not recognize "display:inline-block;" on your #main_navigation li

A "float: left;" on those li must solve the problem.